# Determining Grundy Numbers for an inverted takeaway game

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, game-theory, combinatorial-game-theory

Given the following game, I need to determine a winning strategy and find the set of positions in the kernel. I figure the best way to do so would be with Grundy numbers.

---

Rules:

1. The game consists of two players who make moves in an alternate fashion
2. A move consists of adding either 2, 3, or 5 cents to the pile (which is initially empty).
3. The player who's move brings the pile to a square value (4,9,16,25,36) **or** forces the pile's value to **exceed** 40 cents wins.

---

Now, obviously, all the winning states are kernels (4,9,16,25,36, and "over 41") and therefore have Grundy numbers of zero. However, I am not exactly sure how to find the other nodes in the kernel and the Grundy numbers of the non-kernel nodes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go backward :

If from a position, you can reach a node in the kernel, it is not in the kernel. And if a node is not in the kernel, you can reach a node in the kernel from it.

So 40,39,38,37 are not in the kernel (by adding 5, you reach 41+) but 35 is (because you can only go to 37,38 and 40 that are not). Go on like that !